# How to map non-annotated fields to attributes by default in Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

By default, JAXB maps non-annotated Java field and properties to elements.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so JAXB maps non-annotated Java field and properties to attributes instead of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way with the current spec. Even if you annotate one of the fields with `@XmlValue`, you must explicitly set all other fields with `@XmlAttribute` otherwise marshalling will fail.